# Can we merge timeline bar in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

We have to create chart and need to merge timeline bars (please refer attached link), how to achieve this with highchart timeline chart ?
[timelinemergedbar][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLBw0.jpg

Comment: Why can't you render just one bigger line?

Comment: we have to show multiple callout over bar  , also we have tried to make variable length of bars within Timeline chart and could not able to achieve that's why want merge these.

Comment: I think that you should consider using the x-range series rather than the timeline for your requirements. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f21dxLv8/ The timeline series doesn't allow to merge points.

Comment: can we create callout like timeline in x-range series ?

Comment: Use the annotations for it.